# #1005 - can't create table (errno 150)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run my script in my console Sql

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `invictus`.`Equipo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invictus`.`Equipo` (
  `idPartido` INT NOT NULL,
  `nomEquipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido`, `nomEquipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkequipo_idPartido`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPartido`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Partido` (`idPartido`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `invictus`.`Equipo-Ganador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invictus`.`Equipo-Ganador` (
  `idPartido` INT NOT NULL,
  `equipoganador` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido`, `equipoganador`),
  INDEX `fkeg_equipoganador_idx` (`equipoganador` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkeg_idpartido`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPartido`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Equipo` (`idPartido`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkeg_equipoganador`
    FOREIGN KEY (`equipoganador`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Equipo` (`nomEquipo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

In console display the following error:

Error
consulta SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invictus`.`Equipo-Ganador` (
  `idPartido` INT NOT NULL,
  `equipoganador` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido`, `equipoganador`),
  INDEX `fkeg_equipoganador_idx` (`equipoganador` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkeg_idpartido`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPartido`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Equipo` (`idPartido`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkeg_equipoganador`
    FOREIGN KEY (`equipoganador`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Equipo` (`nomEquipo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1005 - Can't create table 'invictus.Equipo-Ganador' (errno: 150) (Detalles…)
```

I have been searching the possible errors :

1. The two key fields type and/or size doesn’t match exactly.
2. The foreign key name is a duplicate of an already existing key.
3. One of the key field that I am trying to reference does not have an index and/or is not a primary key.

   [This possible errors are here](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't make sense to me -- composite primary keys usually do not.

But, for the foreign key reference, you need to reference *all* columns in the foreign key, not one at a time:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Equipo-Ganador` (
  `idPartido` INT NOT NULL,
  `equipoganador` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido`, `equipoganador`),
  INDEX `fkeg_equipoganador_idx` (`equipoganador` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkeg_idpartido_equipoganador`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPartido`, equipoganador)
    REFERENCES `Equipo` (`idPartido`, nomEquipo)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This works in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ff11).